# How can I switch between workspaces with 3 fingers touchpad in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, touchpad, workspace

I am looking for a way to change between work spaces with my touch pad, I have found other questions like this, and I have tried this solution, but EasyStroke and Touchegg do not work.

I have an ASUS laptop and when running Windows my gesture monitor recognize 3 and even 4 fingers, so the hardware is capable of it. In Ubuntu when I touch with 4 fingers, a launcher is shown (as I get when I press the Super key), but I can not change to another work space with a three-finger swipe.

I added this to Touchegg's config file:

```
<gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="RIGHT">
     <action type="SEND_KEYS">Control+Alt+Left</action>
</gesture>
```

Comment: This interesting question will probably be answered more quickly at http://askubuntu.com which specializes in Ubuntu solutions.